# jQuery Execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, browser, jquery-plugins

My jQuery script has a glitch animating a div position. The bug seems to occur when I click the link right as the page is loading.

Comment: Can you try to publish the site online?  maybe we'll manage to reproduce it

Comment: currently, I cannot reproduce it in FF 3.0.8.  Will be trying a bit with Chrome now

Comment: yeah, it hasn't happened in FF for me either :(

Comment: (btw, the 'enter' for the login in my IE 7 is not working (i don't know if it's just a problem with my browser though).  check it out

Answer (score 8):

> The bug seems to occur when I click
>   the link right as the page is loading

This is because you are using the `ready` function and that executes as soon as the **page has finished loading.**

Thus, if you click on something whilst the page is still loading keep in mind that the JavaScript in that `ready` function has not been executed yet.

---

The reason why you can't always reproduce it most probably because the page will be cached the second time round and you wouldn't have time to click anything before the page has finished loading (since it's cached) and thus the js code would have been executed already when you click.

Comment: well, you can "apply the link" (enclose it in an a tag with a href) in the ready function itself.  So, whilst the page is loading, there is no link and then you add the link in the function

Comment: or else, put code outside of the ready function (that will execute when the browser parses that part of the page, ie not when it has finished loading) that temporarily "removes" the link and then reapply it in the ready function